# How to get to the place from where I can vote on tag wiki edit suggestions?

Tags: support, tag-wiki

I recently acquired enough of that rep stuff to get a new priv thing. But I can't figure out how to use it.

I've tried looking through the "Tags" section and also the "review" section but nothing appears. Is it just that there are no pending edits by other contributors at the moment?

Comment: I know it's annoying (I'm sure annoyed by the tag wiki approval limit) but wait to 2k and things will be nicer. :)

Comment: @Boaz: I know I'm close but I'm heading slowly to Shimonoseki now for the ferry to Korea so my focus may start to blur soon (-:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware, this part is not designed well.  There are several ways:

- There is a [list of suggested edits](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits), but the access to this page is limited to the users with [access to the 10k tools](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools) (≥2,000 rep points during beta, ≥10,000 rep points outside beta).  (hippietrail, thank you for the info in the comment.)
- If you open a tag info page (such as [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/tags/grammar/info)) and it *happens* to have a pending edit, it shows a link labeled “edit pending.”  If you click it, the system gives you options to approve/reject the edit.
- You can try to randomly access a page with the URL https://japanese.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/*nnn* where *nnn* is replaced with a number.  If you are lucky, you arrive at a page with approve/reject options.  I have used this before I reached 2,000 points, so I know it works, but it is very tiring.

It seems to me that the admins do not want users to approve/reject suggested edits.

Comment: Eww this is horrible! Thanks for the tips. Keep in mind that people have been arrested as hackers for URL guessing in some countries!

Comment: @hippietrail: If you try the link to the list of suggested edits in the first bullet, please let me know whether it works for you or not so that I can update this answer.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: No I get a SE "page not found" error page for that link.

Comment: @hippietrail: Thank you for the information.  I updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Should I re-ask this question over on meta.SO? Or will the SO support people see it here anyway since it has the [meta-tag:support] tag?

Comment: @hippietrail: If you want to go with the third option, the numbers nnn for the currently pending edits is between 170 and 187, and it is numbered serially for each edit.  But I do not really recommend this because in my opinion no one should be forced to search a page like this.

Comment: @hippietrail: If you want, please go ahead, but maybe it is better to search before post.  However, if it were me, I would not spend time to fix a broken feature and would just leave it to those who have access to a better tool (that is, users with ≥2,000 rep points).  I cannot be that altruistic.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: I'm going to go ahead and report it as on bug on the main meta site.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: I have searched for previous answers and not found any. As a previous programmer and beta tester it feels like my duty to report bugs to the developer team.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95321/where-how-to-vote-on-approve-tag-wiki-edits-on-a-beta-site

Comment: Thanks for the link!  Let’s hope that there is a better way I do not know.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: No the answer came in and it's designed this way on purpose.

Comment: @hippietrail: Thanks for the update.  Sometimes the reputation system just looks silly, although I understand the admins are trying to find the best compromise between usability and abuse prevention.